# How can I use query cursors in Django nonrel on Google App Engine Python?

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel

How can I use a query cursor with Django-Nonrel? If there is no way currently, it would be appreciated to tell me where to look at in Django-Nonrel.
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Query_Cursors

I'm using Paginator from Django, but it's apparently inefficient with large data.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[djangoappengine](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine) supports cursors:

```
from djangoappengine.db.utils import get_cursor, set_cursor
```

https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/djangoappengine/src/9689b94680ff/db/utils.py

Comment: Thanks Drew! I'm gonna try them later.